# Laravel cashier for Braintree and Stripe

Tags: laravel, braintree-sandbox, laravel-cashier

I am trying to use Laravel cashier for both Braintree and Stripe. I have to use both payment gateways at a time. Can i achieve this with cashier?
For subscription i'm using.

**Braintree**

```
$user->newSubscription('paypalPlaneName', $paypal_plan_id)->create($nonce);
```

And same as with Stripe

```
$user->newSubscription('stripePlaneName', $Stripe_plan_id)->create($stripeToken)
```

And both payment gateways are using same 'users' and 'subscriptions' tables with their fields. 
But how can cashier recognize request is for which payment gateway? Is cashier handle this?
  Can anyone help me with some ideas please?

Comment: I'm looking into this as well, but I don't think it's possible